# "Error in as.POSIXlt.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Tags: r, shiny

I received the error mentioned above when using below code in a another project. Anyone know how to correct this?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(2,
         uiOutput("test_input_ui"),
         sliderInput(
           "test_input",
           label = "Select time",
           min = lubridate::origin,
           max = lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1),
           value = c(lubridate::origin, lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1)),
           step = 5 * 60,
           timeFormat = "%H:%M",
           timezone = "+0000",
           ticks = FALSE
         )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){
  
  output$test_input_ui <- renderUI({input$test_input)}
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
´´´
```

Comment: are you trying to print the text in `renderUI`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same error as you and you have a typo in your definition of `output$test-input_ui`.

Nevertheless, the root cause of your problem is that you are misusing `uiOutput`/`renderUI`.  You need to use them define the output widgets that you want to appear, and then provide the associated renderers elsewhere.  You are skipping the definition of the output widgets and going straight to the renderers.  here's a MWE which, I think, does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(2,
         uiOutput("test_input_ui"),
         sliderInput(
           "test_input",
           label = "Select time",
           min = lubridate::origin,
           max = lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1),
           value = c(lubridate::origin, lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1)),
           step = 5 * 60,
           timeFormat = "%H:%M",
           timezone = "+0000",
           ticks = FALSE
         )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$test_input_ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      textOutput("minTime"),
      textOutput("maxTime")
    )
  })
  output$minTime <- renderText({input$test_input[1]})
  output$maxTime <- renderText({input$test_input[2]})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. The whole point of a `uiOutput` is so you can dynamically render the output, i.e., you want to put it in the server:

```
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(2,
    uiOutput("test_input_ui")
  )
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  output$test_input_ui <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("test_input",
       label = "Select time",
       min = lubridate::origin,
       max = lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1),
       value = c(lubridate::origin, lubridate::origin + days(1) - seconds(1)),
       step = 5 * 60,
       timeFormat = "%H:%M",
       timezone = "+0000",
       ticks = FALSE
     )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, but I still receive the same error. Even though the app shows the Time Range output, no matter what input I choose, it still shows me the same data.